# How to set max date allowed to the user to select in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs

How to allow the user to select a date in the future (maximum the current date + 3 months)?

I have tried below code but it is allowing all future dates. Dates are not disabled after 3 months from current date. I don't want to use a date picker or any date NPM packages.

```js
const [eventDate, setEventDate] = useState(moment())
const eventFutureDate = useState(moment().add(3,'m'))

<Form.Control
  type="date"
  placeholder="select date" name="date"
  value={moment(eventDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
  max={moment(eventFutureDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
  onChange={(e) => setEventDate(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using moment.js, which is [not recommended](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), you need to use a capital `M` inside the add method: `moment().add(3,'M')`.

You should consider replacing moment.js with [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) though; it's a lot smaller and faster.

Another improvement would be to store the formatted date in the state as `event.target.value` in your `onChange` is already formatted. And you don't need to use state for your `eventFutureDate` if you don't change it.

Check the code below:

```js
import addMonths from 'date-fns/addMonths';
import format from 'date-fns/format';

...

const [eventDate, setEventDate] = useState(format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd"));
const maxDate = format(addMonths(new Date(), 3), "yyyy-MM-dd");

...

<Form.Control
  type="date"
  max={maxDate}
  name="date"
  onChange={(e) => setEventDate(e.target.value)}
  placeholder="select date"
  value={eventDate}
/>
```

Comment: how do we achieve for 3 years?